# Convert hex to base64 (Cryptopals challenge 1)

Tags: programming-challenge, rust, base64

I've been spending some time learning Rust and I came across the [Cryptopals Challenges](http://cryptopals.com/).
This is my implementation of challenge 1

> Convert hex to base64 The string:
>
> ```
> 49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d
> ```
>
> Should produce:
>
> ```
> SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t
> ```
>
> So go ahead and make that happen. You'll need to use this code for the
>   rest of the exercises.
>
> Cryptopals Rule: Always operate on raw bytes, never on encoded strings. Only use hex and base64 for pretty-printing.

I did go ahead and pull in a [crate for handling base64 encoding](https://crates.io/crates/base64). It didn't seem important to implement that myself.

```
mod basics {
    extern crate base64;
    use self::base64::encode;

    pub fn hex_to_base64(hex: &str) -> String {
        encode(&hex_to_bytes(hex))
    }

    pub fn hex_to_bytes(hex: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
        hex.chars()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>() //convert to slice-able
            .chunks(2)           //each char is one nibble
            .map(|byte| byte.iter().collect::<String>())
            .map(|byte| u8::from_str_radix(&byte[..], 16).unwrap())
            .collect()
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        use super::*;

        #[test]
        fn can_convert_hex_to_base64() {
            let hex_as_string =
                "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d";
            let base64_as_string =
                "SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t";

            assert_eq!(hex_to_base64(hex_as_string), base64_as_string);
        }

        #[test]
        fn ff_byte_hex_string_to_byte_vector() {
            let hex = "FF";
            assert_eq!(vec![0xFF], hex_to_bytes(hex));
        }

        #[test]
        fn single_byte_hex_string_to_byte_vector() {
            let hex = "2A";
            assert_eq!(vec![0x2A], hex_to_bytes(hex));
        }

        #[test]
        fn multibyte_hex_string_to_byte_vector() {
            let hex = "2ABE";
            assert_eq!(vec![0x2A, 0xBE], hex_to_bytes(hex));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Hex string to Base64](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147670/32521)

Comment: Yeah. I’ve seen that @Shepmaster. Makes me think I might go back and implement base64 at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pub fn hex_to_base64(hex: &str) -> String {
    encode(&hex_to_bytes(hex))
```

I would not `use self::base64::encode` and instead refer to `base64::encode` here so that it is clearer what is being encoded.

```
}

pub fn hex_to_bytes(hex: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    hex.chars()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>() //convert to slice-able
```

Given that you are doing hex, which is all in the ASCII range, you may want to use `as_bytes()` which will give you a slice of bytes without copying the whole string into a new `Vec`.

```
        .chunks(2)           //each char is one nibble
```

What happens if the string length isn't a multiple of two?

```
        .map(|byte| byte.iter().collect::<String>())
```

`byte` isn't correct here as it is a slice of `char`s. Further, if you don't use `chars()` as I suggest as above, you can use `std::str::from_utf8` to get a `&str` without allocating a new `String`.

```
        .map(|byte| u8::from_str_radix(&byte[..], 16).unwrap())
```

`byte` really isn't correct here as you have a `String`.  Additionally, there is no need to take a slice.

```
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: It took some doing, but I did end up with something I feel is a little bit better. Thanks!
`hex.as_bytes().chunks(2).map(|nibbles| str::from_utf8(&nibbles).unwrap()).map(|s| u8::from_str_radix(&s, 16)).collect::<Vec<u8>>()`